# valgrind doesn't recognize invalid write

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, valgrind

Valgring doesn`t detect memory errors.

I am using valgrind 3.11, gcc 5.4.0 under ubuntu and
 have an incorrect code in my program, like in the sample.

I analyzed this program, using valgrind. But valgrind doesn't report about any errors.

```
  #include <string.h>
   int main(){
     int a[3];
     memcpy(a,"aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhh", 24);
     return 0;
   }
```

What's wrong with valgrind?

Comment: Maybe you have 8 byte `ints`

Comment: In this  sample program after increasing the third parameter  valgrind reported about stack crush. But in my big app it doesn`t help.
I have there
```memcpy(a,"aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccddddddeeeeeffffffggggggvvvvvbbbbbbbsdddddd", 40);
```
And valgrind still doesn't work

Comment: Last time I checked, `valgrind` doesn't detect most stack issues.  If you're using a recentish gcc/clang, you can add `-fsanitize=address` to your flags.

Comment: Without `-fsanitize=address` valgrind may not detect anything, as all writes may be valid. And this code can be optimized into no-op.

Comment: if we were to assume that, as john suggested, sizeof(int) is indeed 8, then there would be no memory error to report.

Comment: ```sizeof(a)``` returns 12

Answer (score 3):

*valgrind* doesn't know *a*, not its size then, while you stay in the stack it cannot detect the error

---

To compare, having that :

```
#include <string.h>
int main(){
  int * a = new int[3];
  memcpy(a,"aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhh", 24);
  return 0;
}
```

*valgrind* can detect the error because it knows the size of the allocated block :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==16164== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16164== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16164== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16164== Command: ./a.out
==16164== 
==16164== Invalid write of size 8
==16164==    at 0x4865F44: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==16164==  Address 0x4bc9f60 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==16164==    at 0x48485F0: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==16164==    by 0x105A7: main (v.cc:3)
==16164== 
==16164== Invalid write of size 8
==16164==    at 0x4865F54: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so)
==16164==  Address 0x4bc9f68 is 4 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==16164==    at 0x48485F0: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==16164==    by 0x105A7: main (v.cc:3)
==16164== 
==16164== 
==16164== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16164==     in use at exit: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==16164==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 20,236 bytes allocated
==16164== 
==16164== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16164==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==16164==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16164==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16164==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16164==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16164== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==16164== 
==16164== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16164== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```